# Calling Javascript function in Applescript

Tags: javascript, applescript

I am trying to automate a javascript function call on an external webpage.

the line of code I want to execute is triggered by the click of this div

```
<div class="vote_btn 151" onclick="vote('151', 'California Square Red Paso','145');">&nbsp;VOTE ►</div>
```

Instead of automating the clicking of the div, I am just skipping to calling the vote function. I am attempting to do this in two browsers. Here is the applescript for safari:

```
tell application "Safari" to do JavaScript "vote('151', 'California Square Red Paso', '145');" in document 1
```

and for chrome:

```
tell application "Google Chrome"

    tell window 1

        tell tab 1

            execute javascript "vote('151', 'California Square Red Paso', '145');"

        end tell

    end tell

end tell
```

the problem is, I am getting weird errors. For chrome, it says "vote is not defined" and safari "variable vote is not defined". It seems like my applescripts aren't able to access the javascript? I know there are similar questions to this on stackoverflow but I have read and tried all of the solutions from them with no successful results. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What happens if you type the JavaScript line in the browser bar? That is, what happens if you type "javascript:vote('151', 'California Square Red Paso', '145');" in the URL bar? What shows up in the error console?

Comment: disregard the last response, it is now giving me the same error in safari "can't find variable vote"

Comment: It sounds like the browser itself can’t access the function, at least within the scope that AppleScript has access to. If you can’t do it from the browser bar, I don’t think AppleScript can do it either. Is it possible that the <div> example you have above is part of an iframe? If so, you would need to access it via that frame. (See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/251420/invoking-javascript-code-in-an-iframe-from-the-parent-page if that’s the case.)